# Unknown iphone code

Tags: iphone

I am looking at a project which was provided me by my organization, for study.

The problem is that in this project I found some code which I never saw before.

Please  tell me why the following code is written.

```
-(void)notifications
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: 
    @selector(hideViews) name: @"Hide" object:nil]; 
}
```

This problem arose because this project has only some code for designing.

Sorry if this is a silly question...

Comment: It might help if you told us which programming laguage. Or is that a test - only the one who knows the language can answer?   Seriously, the more information you give, the more help you can expect to recevie in return.

Comment: @LeonixSolutions - It's tagged with iphone-sdk which implies Objective-C. The syntax is also clearly Objective-C. NSNotificationCenter itself is an Objective-C thing :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying (+1). Sorry to be so dumb. Lear something new every day ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read up on how notifications work in Cocoa. Consult Apple's documentation for more information: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Basically, `NSNotificationCenter` is a class that broadcasts `NSNotifications` from one object to potentially many observing objects. One object can post a notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NotificationName" object:self];
```

and other objects can listen for this notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationHandler:) object:theObjectThatPostedTheNotification];
```

Then, when the first object posts the notification, `NSNotificationCenter` will notify the other observing object, and `notificationHandler:` gets called.